# How may I store an array of Xamarin.Forms.Point in SQLite?

Tags: c#, arrays, sqlite, xamarin.forms

How may I store an array of `Xamarin.Forms.Point` in an SQLite database?

I have the following method:

```
async void OnSaveButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var temp = padView.Points;
    var tempArray = padView.Points.ToArray();

    var databaseItem = new DatabaseItem
    {
        Name = Name.Text,
        Date = Date.Date.ToString(),
        //PadViewPoints = 
    };
    //var databaseItem = (DatabaseItem)BindingContext;
    await App.Database.SaveItemAsync(databaseItem);
    await Navigation.PopAsync();
}
```

Given there is a signature on the `padView`, when stepping through the aforementioned method, I see that `tempArray` has a value of `Xamarin.Forms.Point[76]`.

I'd like to store this array of points in the database so that I may load it later when loading the item.

Comment: if you just need to store it, and not dyamically query it, then you could serialize it to json and store as text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jason said, you could store it as a string, a practical implementation of that would be:

```
var temp = padView.Points;
var tempArray = padView.Points.ToArray();

var databaseItem = new DatabaseItem
{
    Name = Name.Text,
    Date = Date.Date.ToString(),
    PadViewPointsString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tempArray)
};
```

And in the DatabaseItem class:

```
public class DatabaseItem
{
    // All other properties

    string padViewPointsString;
    public string PadViewPointsString
    {
        get => padViewPointsString;
        set
        {
            padViewPointsString = value;
            PadViewPoints = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Xamarin.Forms.Point[]>(value);
        }
    }

    public Xamarin.Forms.Point[] PadViewPoints { get; set; }
}
```

This will make the class deserialize the string every time you set it's value (e.g. when you get it from the serialized database).

Obs. This example is using Newtonsoft.Json library

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you; do you know how I may go about setting the `padView.Points` to the Deserialized `Point` array (for example on load)? Would it need to be `IEnumerable<Point>`?

Comment: The property PadViewPoints of the DatabaseItem class is an array of Point (Point[]) so, based on the example that you gave, it should be `var someDatabaseItem = new DatabaseItem() { PadViewPoints = padView.Points.ToArray() }`. Or, if you already have the variable: `someDatabaseItem.PadViewPoints = padView.Points.ToArray()`.